# Widgets behaving strangely when using "setlayout(null)"

Tags: java, swing, layout, awt, null-layout-manager

I'm doing the following call in my code:

```
...
setLayout(null);
...
```

I'm trying to place a button and a textfield by specifying their x and y coordinates.

The problem when I run the program (either with Eclipse or BlueJ) is that I need to run on the panel up to the position of the button and the textfield in order to see respectively the button and the textfield.

When I find the textfield, it is small. Only when I start writing it assumes the size I specified.

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: the rule is to **NOT** do any ui without a LayoutManager. Breaking that rule will _inevitably_ bring pain ...

Answer (score 7):

1. Avoid setLayout (null), unless you have a very good reason for it. You can learn about layout managers here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html
2. If you still want to use a null layout, you have to set the width and height of the component, not just its x and y position (see the setSize method).

From the link mentioned above:

> Although we strongly recommend that you use layout managers, you can
>   perform layout without them. By setting a container's layout property
>   to null, you make the container use no layout manager. With this
>   strategy, called absolute positioning, you must specify the size and
>   position of every component within that container. One drawback of
>   absolute positioning is that it does not adjust well when the
>   top-level container is resized. It also does not adjust well to
>   differences between users and systems, such as different font sizes
>   and locales.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using the `setBounds` method instead of the `setLocation`

```
    JTextField tf = new JTextField(10);
    Dimension d = tf.getPreferredSize();
    tf.setBounds(x, y, d.width, d.height);
```

Of course, if you're using a null Layout manager, you also need to take care of your `preferredSize`.  Here's an example that incorporates all the major aspects:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestProject extends JPanel{

    public TestProject(){
        super(null);

        JTextField tf = new JTextField(10);
        add(tf);

        Dimension d = tf.getPreferredSize();        
        tf.setBounds(10, 20, d.width, d.height);

    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
        //Hard coded preferred size - but you'd probably want 
        //to calculate it based on the panel's content 
        return new Dimension(500, 300);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {


        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
                frame.setContentPane(new TestProject());    
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```